# Best positioning of snubber capacitors for Full-Bridge transistors

Tags: snubber, full-bridge

Two options for the location of snubber (film) capacitors.
In the first circuit, both capacitors stand up to before the bridge. In the second variant, each capacitor stands next to the half-bridge.

I suppose that the second option is better, since the emissions of each half-bridge will be extinguished next to it, and not pass through the bridge and are already extinguished before it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp8cBL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Question:** Which snubber capacitor arrangement is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The layout solution that gives the shortest loop area will be the best performing one, however by not placing them on the same spot you may also get a little bit higher risk of a small resonance between the snubber capacitors.

Anyway there is power stage solution where you have several of parallel smal value snubber capacitors all over the board close to the switch stage. which usually gives better performance than bigger than due to lower ESL and ESR overall.

But again shortest loop area and inductance path/resistance will give the best performance overall anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! 
Got it. Any of the options is suitable. The main thing is to shorten the loop as much as possible.